# V-treeview @update:open returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuetify.js, session-storage

I am trying to make the v-treeview not losing its state after page reload.

I achieved that and you can see it [here](https://codepen.io/dmitrysmagin/pen/dyXjYqN). Test it by clicking on the items, opening it, and then reload the page. You will see the state of the menu is saved. In this example if you open the chrome debugger in the console tab you can see that the array is filling up.

However, when I try to implement it into my project it returns nothing, just an empty array, and the session storage is empty as well. Look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1pOJ.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU3ly.png).

That's my piece of code in the template part:

```
 v-list.py-2(v-else, dense)
  v-treeview(v-model="tree", :items="treeData", @update:open="openIds", @update:active="activeIds", :open.sync="openEle", :active.sync="activeEle", item-key="name", activatable, open-on-click)
    template(v-slot:prepend="{item, open}")
      v-list-item(v-if="item.isFolder", link, :href='`/` + item.locale + `/` + item.path', :input-value='path === item.path')
        v-list-item-avatar(size="24", tile)
          v-icon  {{ open ? 'mdi-folder-open' : 'mdi-folder' }}
        v-list-item-title {{ item.title }}
      v-list-item.noFolders(v-else, :href='`/` + item.locale + `/` + item.path', :key='`childpage-` + item.id', :input-value='path === item.path')
        v-list-item-avatar(size="24", tile)
          v-icon mdi-text-box
        v-list-item-title {{item.title}}
```

and the script part:

```
data() {
return {
  openEle: [],
  activeEle: [],
  parentId: [],
  tree: [],
  currentMode: 'browse',
  staticData: [],
  treeData: [],
  currentParent:
    {
      id: 0,
      title: '/ (root)'
    },
  parents: [0],
  loadedCache: []
}
},
computed: {
  path: get('page/path'),
  locale: get('page/locale')
 },
 beforeCreate() {
  console.log("beforeCreated works")
 var openIds = sessionStorage.getItem('openIds');
 if (openIds) {
  this.openEle = JSON.parse(openIds);
  console.log(this.openEle)
 }
  var activeIds = sessionStorage.getItem('activeIds');
  if (activeIds) {
    this.activeEle = JSON.parse(activeIds);
    console.log(this.activeEle)
  }
 },
 async created(){
  console.log("created works")
  if (this.currentMode === 'browse') {
  // this.loadFromCurrentPath()
  await this.loadBrowseData()
  await this.buildTree(this.staticData)
  this.treeData = this.staticData
  }
  },
    methods: {
      openIds(items){
      console.log(items)
      sessionStorage.setItem('openIds', JSON.stringify(items));
      },
     activeIds(items){
      console.log(items)
      sessionStorage.setItem('activeIds', JSON.stringify(items));
     },
     async buildTree(items){
       this.$store.commit(`loadingStart`, 'browse-load')
        for(let item of items){
        if(item.isFolder){
           let result = await this.$apollo.query({
            query: gql`
              query ($parent: Int, $locale: String!) {
                pages {
                  tree(parent: $parent, mode: ALL, locale: $locale) {
                   id
                   path
                   title
                   isFolder
                   pageId
                   parent
                   locale
                 }
                }
              }
            `,
           fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
        variables: {
          parent: item.id,
          locale: this.locale
        }
      })
      item.children = _.get(result, 'data.pages.tree', [])
      for(let kid of item.children){
      if(item.isFolder){
          //kid.name = ""
          kid.children = []
        }
      }
    this.buildTree(item.children)
    console.log(this.treeData )
    }
  }
   this.$store.commit(`loadingStop`, 'browse-load')
},
```

I have tried to put inside different hooks like beforeCreate, created but nothing works. The array is always empty and the session storage, too. Looks like there is not effect in the methods, but if you look at the example on the codepen you can see that it works.

What this might be?

Comment: I think it is better to rely on the `open.sync` prop to synchronize which nodes are open.

Comment: But I have them. Look the template part

Comment: Try changing the item-key on the treeview to `item-key="id"`. Your treenodes don't have a property `name`.